# gmake environment variables missing

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu-make, environment

I am writing a Makefile and need to access the HOSTNAME environment variable.
None of the environment variables are available.  Here's the Makefile:

```
all:
    echo $(HOSTNAME) "b"
```

The output is:

```
echo  "b"
b
```

I am running on ubuntu 14.04 in a VM.  gmake version:

```
make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
```

And yes, the HOSTNAME environment variable is set:

```
/tmp$ echo $HOSTNAME
ubuntu
/tmp$
```

This Makefile works in cygwin.

Do you know why this is not working?

Answer (score 0):

`HOSTNAME` is set by Bash, but when Make runs a shell, it calls `sh`; even if this is a symlink to Bash on your system, it runs in POSIX mode, which disables many Bash-specific behaviors.

Workaround 0; always call `make` with Bash with `HOSTNAME` exported.

```
alias make='export HOSTNAME; make'
```

Workaround 1; use Bash instead of `sh` explicitly.

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
HOSTNAME=$(shell echo "$$HOSTNAME")
```

Workaround 2; call Bash explicitly.

```
HOSTNAME=$(shell bash -c 'echo $$HOSTNAME')
```

Workaround 3; run an external command.

```
HOSTNAME=$(shell uname -n)
```

Out of these, the last one is probably the least obscure as well as the most efficient.